# gmail not responding while connecting through imap?

Tags: php, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I wrote a simple 3 line code for connecting to gmail through imap-php.
i am using 000webhost for running it.
but when i try to open it, it keeps on loading and after some times shows "Problem loading page" or "No data recieved", as if gmail servers are not responding!!
Any suggestions whats the problem?

```
$hostname = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}Inbox";
$username = 'abc@gmail.com';
$password = "abc123";

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password)or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: '    .   imap_last_error());
```

Comment: These 3 simple lines... show these.

Comment: Why do you set `$hostname` like that? Isn't `{imap.gmail.com:993}INBOX` enough? Also check for case-sensitivity.

Comment: i hav tried many combinations, but none of them is working!! i am realyyy fed up!

Comment: Is IMAP enabled for your account in GMail settings?

Comment: Yes.. it shows sometimes connection to the page was reset.

Comment: i think  it is the problem of 000webhost?? am i right?? where do you guys use imap ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$server_name = "imap.gmail.com";
$account_name = "email@mydomain.com";
$account_pwd = "my_account_password"; 

$inbox = imap_open("{".$server_name.":993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", 
$account_name, $account_pwd) OR error_imap_mail("Unable To Open Imap 
Connection","Imap Failure",imap_errors());

function error_imap_mail($subject,$messagetext,$errors) {
    global $report_email;
    $mailfrom = "support@mydomain.com";
    $mailsubject = "$subject";
    $mailbody = "$messagetext\n\n";
    if (count($errors) >0) {
        if (substr($errors[0],0,8) <> "[IN-USE]") {
            array_reverse($errors);
            foreach ($errors as $key=>$value) {
                $mailbody .= "\nErr No.".$key." Error:".$value;
            }
            foreach ($report_email as $value) {
                mail($value, $mailsubject, $mailbody, "From: $mailfrom");
            }
        }#if (substr($err_array[0],0,8) <> "[IN-USE]") {
    }#if (count($errors) >0) {
    exit;
}
```

Get your script to send you the errors if it fails to connect.

Have you turned IMAP on in the account setting in Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$hostname = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$username = 'abc@gmail.com';
$password = "abc123";

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password)or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' .     imap_errors());
```

Also make sure you enable IMAP for you account via GMail settings.

Comment: Not working, in either case it is not showing any error, just keeps on loading.

Comment: Is IMAP enabled for your account in GMail settings?

Comment: Yes it is..i can access my mails through thunderbird but this way it keeps on loading.Do i have to do something with php settings??

Comment: Have you checked that your Web host allows outgoing IMAP connections? Many firewall it by default. If you have shell access, you should do connectivity tests yourself.